# Get destination IP-address of UDP packet

Tags: c#, udp

When using the C# UDPClient to receive data, how do I determine if the received datagram was a broadcast packet or not?

I can determine the source IP-address by reading the endpoint from UdpClient.Receive(endpoint), but I can't figure out how to get the remote IP-address of the packet. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`updClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint` will be of type `IPEndPoint` that has an `Adrdress` Property.

Comment: It's not possible to get the RemoteEndPoint on a connection-less UDP socket, or am I right?

Comment: I have same problem accessing updClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint throws exception - A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Comment: The IPEndPoint class has no IP property.